# How to extract postback data from payload to parameters in Dialogflow V2

Tags: bots, dialogflow-es

I'm stuck in trying to figure this out and I hope someone out there can help me out. I am using the Dialogflow console to create a bot that requests a user to report "something" by providing his/her location and describing the incident. The bot is integrated with Facebook Messenger. One of my intents has a follow up intent which also has a follow up intent like:

```
intent 1
    |
    intent 2
            | intent 3
```

Intent 1 requests for the user's location, intent 2 retrieves the user's location and asks the user to describe the location. Intent 3 SHOULD have all the data in context as it's fulfilled by the a webhook. All the data SHOULD be posted to my server. The problem is that I have failed to get the location data (maybe lat and long) I notice that the data comes back in the following format after the fired event FACEBOOK_LOCATION:

```
{
  "originalDetectIntentRequest": {
    "source": "facebook",
    "payload": {
      "postback": {
        "data": {
        "lat": 14.556761479425,
        "long": 121.05444780425
      },
     "payload": "FACEBOOK_LOCATION"
    },
    "sender": {
      "id": "1588949991188331"
    }
  }
}
```

My question is how to I carry that payload data into my Dialogflow Intent Parameters so that they are carried in context until my webhook is fired? I hope i've explained it well. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the output contexts to save the parameters.

```
{  
  "fulfillmentText":"This is a text response",
  "fulfillmentMessages":[  ],
  "source":"example.com",
  "payload":{  
    "google":{  },
    "facebook":{  },
    "slack":{  }
  },
  "outputContexts":[  
    {  
      "name":"context name",
      "lifespanCount":5,
      "parameters":{  
        "param":"param value"
      }
    }
  ],
  "followupEventInput":{  }
}
```

Once you save the parameters, in the subsequent requests, you can access the parameters by accessing saved context. The lifespanCount will decide how many subsequent calls this context is valid. So in the above, eg. parameters saved in intent 1 will be available till intent 5 (if you have 2 more follow up intents)
You can follow more details [here](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment).

I personally like to use the client library to develop webhooks as they are easy to use, featureful and reduces JSON manipulation errors. If you like to use NodeJs based client, you can follow this [link](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs).

Comment: Thank you. This answer directed me to finding the solution using "OutputContexts" in my webhook response. Thanks for this!

Comment: Glad to hear that.

Comment: I have also gone the route of using the NodeJS based client. I have found I have a lot of flexibility using it. Thank you very much. I have one issue, I am trying to separate the functions dealing with intents into different files (modules) and requiring into the main js file like this: `intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', <required_file_with_function>)` however I get promise errors. How would I solve this?

Comment: better to create a new issue ;)

Comment: :) Thanks! I figured out the problem! I've got one more for you here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51409922/how-to-use-one-mysql-pool-connection-in-many-files-in-a-nodejs-express-app :) Thank you!

Comment: sure did! Looks like i'm on a roll. Guess I'll make my deadline! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Abhinav's answer (and point out what caught me up on this issue).  You need to make sure that the entities you extracted have the lifespan to make it to your webhook fulfillment call. 
[image]

You can adjust the count by editing the number and saving.

> The lifespanCount will decide how many subsequent calls this context is valid. - Abhinav

If your parameters are not showing up in your output context they probably don't have the appropriate lifespan.