# How to use one Mysql pool connection in many files in a NodeJS Express App

Tags: node.js, express, node-mysql

I've been scratching my head at this. I wanted to know if there was an efficient way of creating one Mysql connection and sharing it between different modules in an application served by Express. So far I have the following code at the top in all my JS files that require a database connection of sorts:

```
const db = require('mysql2')
pool = db.createPool(<config details>)

// Below
pool.execute(.. ) // etc
```

I feel like this is an overkill. Is there a way to create one connection, say in express app? Or a separate file and then retrieve that connection whenever I need it? I am thinking something like:

```
// In db.js
const db = require('mysql2')
module.exports = db.createPool(<config details>)

// In file1.js that needs a db connection
let db = require('./db')
db.execute(...)

// In file2.js
let db = require('./db')
db.execute(...)
```

And so on. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: Have you tried doing this?

Comment: @Paul I haven't actually ;D, should I? Let me try that.

Comment: Yep; should work as you described it, your intuition is strong.

Comment: Well i'd be dam**d! It works! :) Great!

Comment: yer welcome (sorta; you knew how to do it already).  When you can, answer  your own question and take credit. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Well, 
I figured it out thanks to @paul. I created a dB file where I placed the MySQL connection and exported it so that other files that need the connection could simply require it.

```
// dB.sql
let MySQL = require(‘mysql2’)
module.exports = MySQL.createPool(require(‘./config’)
```

So any file that includes the file above will have access to the connection.

```
// File that needs pool instance
let pool = require(‘path to dB file’)
```

I hope this helps anyone that’s looking for a similar solution.

Cheers!

Comment: Will it create two different pools if I import it in two different files? Or will it share the pool? Because if there is limit of 200 connection and I import db file in 50 different files with 10 connection in each pool, it might overload if it created different pool for every import.

Comment: @thisisjaymehta this will share the connection. It won't create two pools.

Comment: Ah prefect, thanks.

Comment: Np, happy to assist.